# OutArguments to be used in journey builder (Decision box)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, datetime, custom-activity

My CustomActivity (type- REST) returns an outArgument **which is of DataType - DATE**. I have configured the outArgument correctly and it is visible in the following widgets. MY customActivity is followed by a Decision-box in the journey. I want to take decisions based on the value of this OutArgument in decision-box. I am trying to figure out how do I send this outArgument (Date Type) so that Decision box can parse/read it correctly. The decision box cannot interpret this value and even 'equals' is not working. I have tried to return JSON from customActivity API in formats, but none works

- {“custom_temp_date”: “1/14/2020 12:00:00 AM”}
- {“custom_temp_date”: “datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 23, 12, 36, 47, 493671)”}
- {“custom_temp_date”: “2019-12-15 12:00:00”}
- {“custom_temp_date”: “datetime.date(2020, 1, 23)”}

Note - I am able to use the outArguments successfully if the DataType is bool, string, number or decimal. **Only DATE DataTypes** are not working. Does anyone know what format does the Decision-box needs Date fields?

Comment: I had raised a SFMC support ticket. This is a bug and engineers are working on it. In the mean time, the workaround is to add a wait-step between the customActivity and the decision box. So i added a wait-step of 2 minutes and the decision box is able to parse the date value (passed as String - “2019-12-15 12:00:00”)